# Filtering by colour some contours - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image and I want to analyse the colour of each "object" that appears on it. Below you have an example of the image.

[image]

What I'm doing is obtaining all the contours and then go through all the contours one by one knowing the average of its colour.

```
 for contour in contours:
    mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contour, -1, 255, -1)
    mean = cv2.mean(img, mask=mask)
    print('\t· Mean=',mean)
```

I'm obtaining results like this,

> Mean= (0.25, 110.375, 143.75, 0.0)

I know are the RGBA values. But with this, how can I know for example if it's black?? For example, the next step can be, just show the contours with black (gray scale) inside. How can I do this? Probably it's easy but I'm really lost with this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the bgr value for black?

Comment: mmm (0,0,0) but I suppose I need to work a range or something

Comment: exactly, euclidean distance should work well enough for this. So you can know if a contour contains black if its average color has an euclidean distance with black (or any other color) less than a threshold.

Comment: or as an alternative, use cv::inRange to find blobs of the color you want, and then findContours on these blobs

Comment: Looks hard, I'm going to try it xD